# How to grant remote access permissions to mysql server for user?

Tags: mysql, connection, sql-grant

If I do `SHOW GRANTS` in my mysql database I get

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' 
    IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'some_characters' 
    WITH GRANT OPTION
```

If I am not mistaken, `root@localhost` means that user `root` can access the server only from `localhost`. How do I tell MySQL to grant `root` the permission to access this mysql server from every other machine (in the same network), too?

Comment: Simple change `localhost` to `%` will grant root access to public network. Don't forget to `flush privileges;`

Comment: Adding root@% exposes you to a lot of risk and should not be done. I know this is an old post but that warning should be here. The root account is the first account targeted by attackers, and root@'%' means the root user can connect to your MySQL account from anywhere it likes. There is too much to cover in comments, but you should try to remove as many users@'%' as possible, and any that are declared at that should have very limited privileges. No matter what, you should definitely not add root@'%', and your applications should not expect that account to be present either.

Comment: See also [Enable remote MySQL connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection)

Comment: Hey folks,  should remove the PASSWORD string to this command ... it is causing an error ... just finish with IDENTIFIED BY and then the password itself.

Answer (score 153):

This grants root access with the same password from any machine in `*.example.com`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%.example.com' 
    IDENTIFIED BY 'some_characters' 
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If name resolution is not going to work, you may also grant access by IP or subnet:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.%'
    IDENTIFIED BY 'some_characters'  
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

[MySQL `GRANT` syntax docs.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html)

Comment: I assume `...TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED...` would grant access from everywhere?

Comment: I executed the command in mysql, but `SHOW GRANTS` still shows the same (as in my question). I even did `FLUSH PRIVILGES`. Is there something I miss?

Comment: @Aufwind I wouldn't exepct you to need anything else besides `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`.  Logout and back in, restart the mysqld service if you have access.  Also, be sure that the `skip networking` line is not enabled in your `my.cnf` though that would not account for your `SHOW GRANTS` still not being the same.

Comment: @Aufwind Failing that, you may need to ask over at ServerFault.com instead.

Comment: Note that `IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD` is accompanied by a hashed 41-digit hexadecimal number. Use `IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` if you want to include the password directly.

Comment: @Aufwind @MichaelBerkowski - `SHOW GRANTS;` only shows the grants for the logged in user (eg: root@localhost). If you login as root@example.com and execute `SHOW GRANTS;` from there, it won't show you root@localhost, but it will show you root@%.example.com

To list users you want something like `select user,host,grant_priv from mysql.user;`

Comment: Please also **make sure** that `bind-address` is properly set to a network address (*my.conf*). Mysql defaults to 127.0.0.1 which is not accessible to remotes.

Comment: I got the error: `ERROR 1372 (HY000): Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number`, so I had to first run this command: `select password('some_characters');` then copy/paste the outputted hexadecimal number into the `IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD` line for it to work. Everything worked great, thanks!!

Comment: I preferred @moshe-beeri's answer below for quick-and-dirty, but this answer is obviously better for use in production.

Answer (score 101):

Try:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pa55w0rd' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: umm what is `Pa55w0rd` seems stupid, don't tell me thats the password you want to make. For everybody who tries to login your mysql?

Comment: It just commonly used to give a place holder to password, saying "put your read good password in this place".

Comment: This command with the usual caveat that you'd only want to use it for applications where security is not of concern, e.g. dev or QA.

Comment: if its not working on mac try to change 'root'@'%' with 'root'@'localhost' or  /etc/hosts name of the computer you are granting privileges to.

Comment: Do not forget to run this after: ```FLUSH PRIVILEGES;```

Comment: the "IDENTIFIED BY 'Pa55w0rd'" part may not be required in some cases

Answer (score 49):

You need to take some steps to make sure first mysql and then root user is accessible from outside:

1. Disable `skip-networking` in `my.cnf` (i.e: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`)
2. Check value of `bind-address` in `my.cnf`, if it's set to `127.0.0.1`, you can change it to `0.0.0.0` to allow access from all IPs or whatever ip that you want to connect from.
3. Grant remote access the root user from any ip (or specify your ip instead of `%`)

   ```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'
       IDENTIFIED BY 'your_root_password'
       WITH GRANT OPTION;
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
4. Restart mysql service:

   ```
   sudo service mysql restart
   ```

Comment: You also need to open mysql port 3306 from the firewall otherwise remote clients won't connect

Comment: Just a quick notice on point 2 from @Khashayar: 0.0.0.0 means any IPv4 address. * means ANY address, be it IPv4 or IPv6.

Comment: the location is now `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.conf`.

Answer (score 38):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' 
    IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASS' 
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

`*.* = DB.TABLE` you can restrict user to specific database and specific table.

`'root'@'%'` you can change root with any user you created and % is to allow all IP. You can restrict it by changing %.168.1.1 etc too.

---

If that doesn't resolve, then also modify my.cnf or my.ini
and comment these lines

`bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`
and
`skip-networking` to `#skip-networking`

- Restart MySQL and repeat above steps again.

Raspberry Pi, I found bind-address configuration under `\etc\mysql\mariadb.conf.d\50-server.cnf`

Comment: Only answer that explains the `*.*` and `'user'@'address'` part. Thanks! :)

Comment: Granting ALL on *.* invites hackers in.

Comment: that's why I explained \*.\*

Answer (score 13):

By mysql 8 and later version, you cannot add a user by granting privileges. it means with this query:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' 
    IDENTIFIED BY 'type-root-password-here' 
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

mysql will return this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'written password' at line 1

this means you don't have a root user for % domain. so you need to first insert the user and then grant privileges like this:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Dont forget to replace passwords with your specific passwords.

Comment: It throws an error: ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'

Comment: can we do this fo already created user ? for that it gives access deined error

Answer (score 8):

Those SQL grants the others are sharing do work.  If you're still unable to access the database, it's possible that you just have a firewall restriction for the port.  It depends on your server type (and any routers in between) as to how to open up the connection.  Open TCP port 3306 inbound, and give it a similar access rule for external machines (all/subnet/single IP/etc.).

Answer (score 5):

Two steps:

1. set up user with wildcard:

```
create user 'root'@'%' identified by 'some_characters'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' 
    IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'some_characters' 
    WITH GRANT OPTION
```

2. 

```
vim /etc/my.cnf
```

add the following:

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

restart server, you should not have any problem connecting to it.

Comment: Following along, getting "ERROR 1827 (HY000): The password hash doesn't have the expected format. Check if the correct password algorithm is being used with the PASSWORD() function." Could you explain what I'm getting wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Open the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` file and comment the 
following line:

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Working on Ubuntu 19.4

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was trying to connect to a remote mysql server on cent OS. After going through a lot of solutions (granting all privileges, removing ip bindings,enabling networking) problem was still not getting solved.

As it turned out, while looking into various solutions,I came across iptables, which made me realize mysql port 3306 was not accepting connections.

Here is a small note on how I checked and resolved this issue.

- Checking if port is accepting connections:

```
telnet (mysql server ip) [portNo]
```

-Adding ip table rule to allow connections on the port:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

-Would not recommend this for production environment, but if your iptables are not configured properly, adding the rules might not still solve the issue. In that case following should be done:

```
service iptables stop
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04

Install and ensure mysqld us running..

Go into database and setup root user:

```
sudo mysql -u root
SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'obamathelongleggedmacdaddy';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

Edit mysqld permissions and restart:

```
sudo vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

# edit the line to be this:
bind-address=0.0.0.0

sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

From another machine, test.. Obvs port (3306) on mysqld machine must allow connection from test machine.

```
mysql -u root -p -h 123.456.789.666
```

All the additional "security" of MySql doesn't help security at all, it just complicates and obfuscates, it is now actually easier to screw it up than in the old days, where you just used a really long password.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. But there was a strange problem that even I tryed first those it didnt affect. I updated phpmyadmin page and got it somehow working.

If you need access to local-xampp-mysql. You can go to xampp-shell -> opening command prompt.

Then mysql -uroot -p --port=3306 or mysql -uroot -p (if there is password set). After that you can grant those acces from mysql shell page (also can work from localhost/phpmyadmin).

Just adding these if somebody find this topic and having beginner problems.