# Enable remote MySQL connection: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.1.31 running on Windows XP.

From the **local** MySQL server (192.168.233.142) I can connect as root as follows:

```
>mysql --host=192.168.233.142 --user=root --password=redacted
```

From a **remote** machine (192.168.233.163), I can see that the mysql port is open:

```
# telnet 192.168.233.142 3306
Trying 192.168.233.142...
Connected to 192.168.233.142 (192.168.233.142).
```

But when trying to connect to mysql from the **remote** machine, I receive:

```
# mysql --host=192.168.233.142 --user=root --password=redacted
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.233.163' (using password: YES)
```

I have only 2 entries in mysql.user:

```
Host         User     Password
--------------------------------------
localhost    root     *blahblahblah
%            root     [same as above]
```

What more do I need to do to enable remote access?

**EDIT**

As suggested by Paulo below, I tried replacing the mysql.user entry for % with an IP specific entry, so my user table now looks like this:

```
Host             User     Password
------------------------------------------
localhost        root     *blahblahblah
192.168.233.163  root     [same as above]
```

I then restarted the machine, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Paulo's help lead me to the solution.  It was a combination of the following:

- the password contained a dollar sign
- I was trying to connect from a Linux shell

The bash shell treats the dollar sign as a special character for [expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to an environment variable, so we need to escape it with a backslash. Incidentally, we **don't** have to do this in the case where the dollar sign is the final character of the password.

As an example, if your password is "pas$word", from Linux bash we must connect as follows:

```
# mysql --host=192.168.233.142 --user=root --password=pas\$word
```

Comment: In addition to the above please check /etc/mysql/my.cnf and comment       bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Comment: Alternatively one can use single quotes to prevent expansion of the $: `mysql --host=192.168.233.142 --user=root --password='pas$word'` http://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/500942

Comment: '$' in the password. Priceless. Thanks a ton !!

Comment: after beating my head against the monitor for a while I came across this and it worked. I had a ! and @ in my password.Changed password, flushed privileges and I am back at it.  Thanks!

Comment: Why are you even putting the password on the command line in the first place? That is insane. You need to investigate using my.cnf files.

Answer (score 224):

You have to put this as root:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' with grant option;
```

;

where IP is the IP you want to allow access, USERNAME is the user you use to connect, and PASSWORD is the relevant password.

If you want to allow access from any IP just put `%` instead of your IP

and then you only have to put

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Or restart mysql server and that's it.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without a local mysql client?

Comment: how to remove privileges of a specific ip?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21151255/470749 helped me too because I guess my bind-address setting needed to be commented out.  Granting remote privileges was not enough to get it to work.

Comment: Not explained in the answer, but replace `PASSWORD` with the account password. I tried the above changing only `USERNAME` and `IP` and it did not work for me until I changed `PASSWORD`.

Comment: After doing this, follow what is said in the following answer as well:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/21151255/445438

Comment: @Octavio, What's the minimum set of privileges we have to enable to allow just login?

Comment: You'll get a syntax error in MySQL 8.0. See this for the fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177216/how-to-grant-all-privileges-to-root-user-in-mysql-8-0

Comment: You can also WILDCARD an IP by using %. For example: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME' @ '10.1.1.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' with grant option;

Comment: For allowing any IP, use `.... TO 'USERNAME' @ '%' IDENTIFIED BY ...`

Comment: This is insanely bad advice! You are allowing the user to do anything they want to do, up to dropping databases and more. You should only grant what the user needs, which could be as little as `GRANT SELECT` on one table in one database.

Answer (score 94):

I was getting the same error after granting remote access until I made this:

From `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

In newer versions of mysql the location of the file is
`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

(comment this line: `bind-address  = 127.0.0.1`)

Then run `service mysql restart`.

Comment: Or, change it to bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Comment: Only commenting out `bind-address` didn't work for me. Either `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` or `bind-address = <server_ip>` works.

Answer (score 60):

By default in MySQL server remote access is disabled. The process to provide a remote access to user is.

1. Go to my sql bin folder or add it to `PATH`
2. Login to root by `mysql -uroot -proot` (or whatever the root password is.)
3. On success you will get `mysql>`
4. Provide grant access all for that user.

---

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Here IP is IP address for which you want to allow remote access, if we put `%` any IP address can access remotely.

Example:

```
C:\Users\UserName> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin

C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin>mysql -uroot -proot

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.27 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.25 sec)
```

This for a other user.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'testUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testUser';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Hope this will help

Comment: +1 for Excellent details, it really helped me to see that `0 rows affected` is the norm :) Also, `service mysqld restart` is recommended at the end. [`mysqld` is sometimes just `mysql`]

Comment: #Note: For the version 5.6+, use "grant all on..."

(without the privileges)

Answer (score 9):

Do you have a firewall ? make sure that port 3306 is open.

On windows , by default mysql root account is created that is permitted to have access from localhost only unless you have selected the option to enable access from remote machines during installation .

creating or update the desired user with '%' as hostname .

example :

```
CREATE USER 'krish'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: The server reply with "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for"... if  a firewall block will get a timeout...

Comment: just wanted to post first . my bad

Comment: @Krish - Everything you suggested is already covered in the question

Answer (score 7):

1. Try to `flush privileges` again.
2. Try to restart server to reload grants.
3. Try create a user with host "192.168.233.163". "%" appears to not allow all (it's weird)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but to no avail.  I updated the question with your suggestions.

Comment: Try create another user, and dont forget to set all grants: `CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: I had a situation today where 'user'@'%' did indeed not grant 'user' remote access from just 'any' host but instead defining the specific host IP did. I then found out after further testing that this was caused by me binding the sql server to "0.0.0.0". When I commented the binding address completelyin the servers config, suddenly it'd work as expected. Not very intuitive indeed.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was trying to connect to a remote mysql server on cent OS. After going through a lot of solutions (granting all privileges, removing ip bindings,enabling networking) problem was still not getting solved.

As it turned out, while looking into various solutions,I came across iptables, which made me realize mysql port 3306 was not accepting connections.

Here is a small note on how I checked and resolved this issue.

- Checking if port is accepting connections:

  telnet (mysql server ip) [portNo]
- Adding ip table rule to allow connections on the port:

  iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
- Would not recommend this for production environment, but if your iptables are not configured properly, adding the rules might not still solve the issue. In that case following should be done:

  service iptables stop

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using dynamic ip just grant access to 192.168.2.% so now you dont have to worry about granting access to your ip address every time.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with remote login to MYSQL for my Amazon EC2 Linux instance. Found the solution was to make sure my security group included an inbound rule for MySQL port 3306 to include my IP address (or 0.0.0.0/0 for anywhere). Immediately could connect remotely as soon as I added this rule.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver is that special characters in the password aren't handled.

"Warning – You might have a serious headache with MySQL ODBC 3.51 if the password in your GRANT command contains special characters, such as ! @ # $ % ^ ?. MySQL ODBC 3.51 ODBC Driver does not support these special characters in the password box. The only error message you would receive is “Access denied” (using password: YES)"  -   from http://www.plaintutorials.com/install-and-create-mysql-odbc-connector-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

The user/host combination may have been created without password.

I was assuming that when adding a new host for an existing user (using a GUI app), the existing password would also be used for the new user/host combination.

I could log in with

```
mysql -u username -p PASSWORD
```

locally, but not from IPADDRESS with

```
mysql -u --host=HOST -p PASSWORD
```

(I could actually log in from IPADDRESS without using a password)

```
mysql -u --host=HOST
```

Setting the password allowed access:

```
set password for '<USER>'@'<IPADDRESS>' = '<PASSWORD>';
```

Comment: Thank you, I spent a lot of time trying to get connected remotely to my Mysql server and this line helped a lot. When setting the user's password, I got the error `ERROR 1372 (HY000): Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number` which led me to this article: https://knowmysql.blogspot.com/2013/09/mysql-grant-password-error-error-1372.html After following those steps, I could finally connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

New location for mysql config file is

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

My case is absolutely simple.

You may have this problem in case if you type in WRONG password. No create user is needed (user already existed), no other permissions. Basically make sure that the password is correct. So make double-sure **the password** is correct

Answer (score 0):

My problem was exact same but resolution or cause was totally different from above all
I had "auth_socket" enabled for my user, so after recreating use without auth_socket setting as earlier, it connected **fine**

fyi, make sure to not have below like setting

```
UPDATE user SET plugin='auth_socket' WHERE User='';
```