# MySQL root access from all hosts

Tags: mysql, authentication

I've installed MySQL server on a remote Ubuntu machine. The `root` user is defined in the `mysql.user` table this way:

```
mysql> SELECT host, user, password FROM user WHERE user = 'root';
+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host             | user | password                                  |
+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost        | root | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| ip-10-48-110-188 | root | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| 127.0.0.1        | root | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| ::1              | root | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I can access with user `root` from the same remote machine command-line interface using the standard `mysql` client. Now I want to **allow root access from every host on the internet**, so I tried adding following row (it's an exact duplicate of the first row from previous dump, except for the `host` column):

```
mysql> SELECT host, user, password FROM user WHERE host = '%';
+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host             | user | password                                  |
+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| %                | root | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

But my client on my personal PC continues to tell me (I obscured the server IP):

> SQL Error (2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '46.x.x.x' (10061)

I can't tell if it's a authentication error or a network error. On the server firewall I enabled port *3306/TCP* for *0.0.0.0/0*, and that's ok for me...

Comment: can you telnet to the machine on port 3306

Comment: most likely the MySQL daemon does not listen on 46.x.x.x but on localhost only. Look for `bind-address` in my.cnf

Comment: So, the world+dog now have the hash of your root password, the knowledge that root is accessible from any host on the Internet and the first byte of your IP address.  You don't think this is just a *tiny* bit concerning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable remote MySQL connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection)

Answer (score 447, accepted):

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comments, since MySql 8 you need to first explicitly create the user, so the command will look like:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

**Original answer:**

There's two steps in that process:

a) Grant privileges. As root user execute with this substituting `'password'` with your current root password :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

b) bind to all addresses:

The easiest way is to **comment out** the line in your `my.cnf` file:

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

and restart mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

By default it binds only to localhost, but if you comment the line it binds to all interfaces it finds. Commenting out the line is equivalent to `bind-address=*`.

To check where mysql service has binded execute as root:

```
netstat -tupan | grep mysql
```

**Update For Ubuntu 16:**

Config file is (now)

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

(at least on standard Ubuntu 16)

Comment: Ok, the problem was the binding address. Thank you. @Darhazer Thank you too :)

Comment: To query current grants: `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%';

Comment: To also allow root@% to grant permissions to other users, immediately after step (a) run: GRANT USAGE ON \*.\* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: Config file is (now) /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf (at least on standard Ubuntu 16)

Comment: I just needed to do this, to be able to remotely connect to the server remotely: `USE mysql; UPDATE user SET Grant_priv='Y' WHERE user='root';`

Comment: where to find `my.cnf` file ?

Comment: check the package description for your distribution or try to use "find" in /etc with the appropriate parameters

Comment: Recommend to use: FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: Oh, my problem is on where ubuntu 16 configuration file located. thanks

Comment: 'password' seems not to be a selector! Only when used the root password (e.g. 1234) in there, I could finally connect.

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '1234' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: Hello hovanessyan, is it safe to comment "bind-address" attribute?

Comment: @learner the bind-address property defines the network address to which the server will bind to. In the case of 127.0.0.1, which is the loopback network interface, the server will bind to localhost only. In this context I believe it is safe, yes.

Comment: One should know that you need to replace 'password' for the current root password or you'll change it...I accidentally changed my root password to `password` in a answer that exposes root user to the internet...

Comment: thank you @Caleb for the bit about needing to allow grant privileges

Comment: Starting with MySQL 8.0 and up, you can no longer (implicitly) create a user with the `GRANT` command. Use `CREATE USER` followed by `GRANT`.

For example, `CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: It might look like that the command GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO does not work for a root user or changing password, eg. just creating a new all-hosts user, since the command creates a user or changes the password, but for the root user changes (or creates) the password only for the all-hosts " type of user not for the localhost version, and it cannot reset the account to an empty password, to be passwordless. Whereas when not creating/changing the password for a non-root user,it changes it both for the localhost and all-hosts version.Password is possible to remove by manually emptying the col

Comment: More over the clause 'Identified by' seems to serves as both, the selector and a password setter, since if you use it for some non existing user, it will create it, but if you use it for an existing user but with an incorrect password, then it won't change anything

Comment: problem running first step: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'' at line 1 USE INSTEAD THIS COMMAND: GRANT ALL ON root.* TO 'root'@'localhost';

Answer (score 49):

Run the following query:

```sql
use mysql;
update user set host='%' where host='localhost'
```

NOTE: Not recommended for production use.

Comment: This is not the perfect solution. It may work. For me it produced an error: 
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '%-root' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @Scriptlabs, chances are there are more than one entries in user table with a host of 'localhost'. And more than one row with root, including root.localhost, root.127.0.0.1, root.::1. So you are better off adding a separate user rather than updating, which is why I am downvoting this answer.

Comment: isn't FLUSH PRIVILEGES; also necessary right after ?

Comment: this is working for me. try this.
`update mysql.user set host='%' where user='root'`

Comment: use double "" instead '' or you will get an error

Comment: you have to restart mysql or the server for the changes to take effect

Comment: from root I received the following error: ```View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them```

Answer (score 28):

MYSQL 8.0 - open mysql command line client

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

use mysql

```sql
UPDATE mysql.user SET host='%' WHERE user='root';
```

Restart mysql service

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near '\*.* TO 'root'@'localhost'' at line 1

Comment: Got an error on this too. I omitted the backslash, and it worked.

Comment: This answer worked for me. Great!

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes

> bind-address = 127.0.0.1

should be

> bind-address = *

Answer (score 5):

MariaDB running on Raspbian - the file containing bind-address is hard to pinpoint. MariaDB have some [not-very-helpful-info](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/) on the subject.

I used

```
# sudo grep -R bind-address /etc
```

to locate where the damn thing is.

I also had to set the privileges and hosts in the mysql like everyone above pointed out.

And also had some fun time opening the 3306 port for remote connections to my Raspberry Pi - finally used [iptables-persistent](http://blog.mxard.com/persistent-iptables-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian).

All works great now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using AWS LightSail and for my instance to work, I had to change:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind-address = <Private IP Assigned by Amazon>
```

Then I was able to connect remotely.

Answer (score 1):

if you have many networks attached to you OS, yo must especify one of this network in the bind-addres from my.conf file.
 an example:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 127.100.10.234
```

this ip is from a ethX configuration.

Comment: Please add more detail.  In what file or framework does that setting need to happen?  Please be more specific about the ethX configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the "bind-address" setting was the problem. Commenting this setting in `my.cnf` did **not** help, because in my case mysql set the default to 127.0.0.1 for some reason.

To verify what setting MySql is currently using, open the command line on your local box:

```
mysql -h localhost -u myname -pmypass mydb
```

Read out the current setting:

```
Show variables where variable_name like "bind%"
```

You should see 0.0.0.0 here if you want to allow access from all hosts. If this is not the case, edit your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and set bind-address under the [mysqld] section:

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Finally restart your MySql server to pick up the new setting:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Try again and check if the new setting has been picked up.

Answer (score 1):

Update the `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` in the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and from the mysql command line allow the `root` user to connect from any Ip.

Below was the only commands worked for **mysql-8.0** as other were failing with error `syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'abcd'' at line 1`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
UPDATE mysql.user SET host='%' WHERE user='root';
```

Restart the mysql client

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score -2):

`mysql_update` is what you need.

I don't know why anyone would follow the more complex ways of correcting this issue, when MySql graciously built a tool that already does this...