# access database remotely

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, privileges

I have an ubuntu server with mysql installed, at one point I saw the php code running on the server could access mysql but I can't access mysql remotely, for another server or sequal pro.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
mysql> GRANT ALL on *.* TO 'thomas'@'%';
mysql> exit
$ mysql -u thomas -p
mysql> show grants;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for thomas@localhost                                                                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'thomas'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '[ENCRYPTEDPASSWORD]' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> exit
$ mysql -u thomas -p -h [SERVERIP]
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'thomas'@'[SERVERNAME]' (using password: YES)
```

Update:

I wen't in and dropped all the users that where made (some didn't have passwords) I was going by the `mysql.user` table and using the `drop user` command.

```
CREATE USER 'thomas'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'thomas'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'thomas'@'[SERVERIP]' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'thomas'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]';
```

the table now looks like this:

```
+--------------+------------------+
| Host         | User             | 
+--------------+------------------+
| localhost    | root             | 
| localhost    | phpmyadmin       | 
| 127.0.0.1    | root             | 
| ::1          | root             | 
| localhost    | debian-sys-maint | 
| localhost    | thomas           | 
| [SERVERIP]   | thomas           | 
| %            | thomas           | 
+--------------+------------------+
```

Comment: check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11225588/1007273

Comment: Most probably mysqld is not listening on the correct Ethernet interface...

Comment: @hovanessyan The listening **must** be OK, else hew ouldn't get `Access denied` but `Can't connect`

Comment: Keep in mind, the password for `thomas@localhost` is not necessarily the same as for `thomas@%`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'thomas'@'localhost'
```

but you are not on `localhost`. You might want to try

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'thomas'@'%'
```

Ofcourse you have to add `IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` if you so desire

Comment: I was missing `PRIVILEGES`, but it still doesn't work. No matter what I do, what user I do it under `show grants;` does not come back with anything other than `localhost`.

Comment: I can see that the `mysql.user` is changed but nothing in `show grants;`.

Comment: AFAIK `SHOW GRANTS` will show only the **applicable** grants - so if you are logged in from localhost, you won't see the global privileges.

Comment: Thanks @Eugen_Rieck makes sense. Any reason why I still can't connect?

Comment: Did you forget to give the `'thomas'@'%'` a password? I updated my answer

Comment: ok.. i got it working when im ssh'd into the server and I run `mysql -u thomas -p -h [SERVERIP]`. This is progress right? Sequal pro a mysql client still won't connect.

Comment: php won't connect either... =[