# Yii: How to connect remotely to a database?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to connect to a db remotely using the `Yii framework`

Is there any specific setting because i can't connect to the db.

```
'db' => array(
    'class' => 'PortalDbConnection',
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=192.168.0.2;dbname=mydb',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'tablePrefix' => '',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'enableParamLogging' => true,
    'enableProfiling' => true,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
),
```

**Error**

> 2013/10/16 09:14:22 [error] [exception.CDbException] SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql5.ms.domain.net' (13)
>   2013/10/16 09:14:22 [info] [application] User: Guest (ID: )

Comment: nothing is wrong with this code,, issue is here `192.168.0.2`,, allow the access for * systems or atleast this system where the Yii/PHP code resides,

Comment: take a look at this.. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: still, not able to connect; will keep this article updated when i fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is valid for me:

```
'db'=>array( 
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=192.168.1.96;dbname=dbname',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'enableProfiling'=>true,
        'enableParamLogging' => true,
    ),
```

Do you have **configurated** on the DB **server** the %root **access**, from **remote**?

**Edited:**

For configure remote access:

There's two steps in that process:

***a)*** Grant privileges. As root user execute:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

***b)*** bind to all addresses:

The easiest way is to comment out the line in your my.cnf file:

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

and restart mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

@hovanessyan solution: [MySQL root access from all hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223235/mysql-root-access-from-all-hosts)

Comment: what do you mean with %root access?

Comment: root@% means root can access from any host.  I think by default root can only access from localhost.  Of course that then means that any hacker can attempt to access your server with root access from any client that can get to it. Better not to use root, and to restrict the user that you are using to the server that your Yii application runs on.

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem of server accessebily, not user access. Check number of port of mysql server (must be 3306, if not - use `mysql:host=192.168.0.2;port=<your port>;dbname=mydb`) and try to `ping 192.168.0.2` (or maybe can run this `nmap -p 3306 -sT 192.168.0.2`, it from [here](http://forum.linuxcareer.com/threads/1634-How-do-I-ping-a-specific-port-of-a-remote-server)) from the where yii placed