# Not able to connect to database. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, database

***EDIT!*** I see that many people are answering to my question, and thank you. But most of you are talking about some user name, which I do not get. I am actually using this example over here:

http : //people. cis.ksu .edu/~hankley/d764/tut06/GopisettyPHP.html

and am trying to make it using this reference. Over there is something completely different, cis-id, which I do not understand. Yes, I do not understand what the cis id is, which is in here:

$con = mysql_connect("sql107.freezoy.com",***"CIS-ID"***,"REDACTED INFORMATION");

And also, many people are saying that I wrote name instead of Full Name and phone instead of Phone Number, but that is not referring to the table. The 'phone' and 'name' are the names I gave to the inputs in the HTML form.

Thanks,
Kind Regards,
Danish Humair

***BACK TO THE OLD POST***

**Well, I am currently working on a website. Basically what happens is that you submit your name and phone number and it is inserted into the database. This may be a very 'newbie`ish' question, but I need your help.**

Well, I made the table in the database and everything. Then I put this code into the HTML document:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="main/shortcut_icon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/common.css" />
    <title>
      Danish Core
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="title">
      Welcome! Here is a simple form that uses PHP and MySQL!
    </p>
    <p>
      Note: Please do not submit any sensitive information, as all that you submit will be saved into our database. Also, please do not spam by submitting irrelevant (or related) text.
    </p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
      Full Name:
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <br />
      <br />
      Phone Number:
      <input type="text" name="phone" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Well, and the 'insert.php' mentioned in the form's opening tag:

```
<html>
<body>


<?php
$con = mysql_connect("sql107.freezoy.com","frzoy_15640861_main","REDACTED INFORMATION");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("frzoy_15640861_main", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO ClientInformation (name, phone)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[phone]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a screen shot of my MySQL table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGITc.png

And also my host's information:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA3vK.png

And the error is this:
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'frzoy_15640861_main'@'192.168.0.40' (using password: YES)

I believe that it is most likely that the information to connect to the database was incorrect in the insert.php file. I have included the database information with the password redacted, so - if you could please help me with the trouble I am having thanks!

Thank you for reading!
Kind Regards,
Danish Humair

Comment: I'd remove the real credentials and put in some dummy values if I were you.

Comment: avoid `mysql` functions as they are depricated. Switch to `mysqli` or `pdo`. If you have this code on your server, than you use the term `localhost` instead of `sql107.freezoy.com` since you try to connect from outside to the inside, while you are already inside. This indeed may cause an error. Try it with `localhost`.

Comment: As per this [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GA3vK.png) Your mysql username is frzoy_15640861

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Database fields are different.

`Full Name` and your inserting `name`

`Phone Number` and you are inserting `phone`

Rename you DB table fields to `name` and `phone`

**Note:**

Don't use mysql_ functions. They are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the user exists and its password is correct but is not permitted to connect from the IP that the connection is coming from. [Check this old question in StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223235/mysql-root-access-from-all-hosts)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from the screenshot you're trying to connect with the username `frzoy_15640861_main` which is the db name instead. The user should be `frzoy_15640861`. Maybe the issue is in the credentials you are providing. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Guys, you were right, but there was another thing that had to be done.**

You guys were right that I inserted the database name in place of the username, and that I had written name and phone rather than Full Name and Phone Number. There was yet another problem. I was still not able to insert the data as the Table columns Full Name and Phone Number had a space in them! (between full and name, and phone and number)

This is though pretty weird, but removing those spaces in the table did the trick!

**Thank you all for helping.**
Kind Regards, Danish Humair.