# dockerizing wordpress with mysql installed on the host machine

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, docker

I am trying to run Wordpress on docker with mysql installed on my local host machine (ubuntu 14.04)

I am using the docker image  from here: https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

I passed my host ip address (192.168.1.1) and the port (3306) as shown below

```
sudo docker run -it --name wp -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=192.168.1.1:3306 -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=root -d wordpress
```

but I am getting the following error, when I try to run the image

```
"MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused"
```

Below are the exact steps, I follow

```
sudo docker run -it --name wp -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=192.168.1.1:3306 -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=root -d wordpress

sudo docker ps -a

sudo docker commit <container_id> myuser/eslwp

sudo docker images

sudo docker run -i -t myuser/eslwp
```

Comment: Is your mysql instance configured to allow remote connections?

Comment: Yes, bind address has been commented in /etc/mysql/my.cnf   # bind-address  = 127.0.0.1

Comment: Did you add `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` there instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think Adrian is right, verify if your mysql allow remote connection for `root`. You can check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11225588/210085) to troubleshoot.

Other then that, it might be your firewall blocking the connection.

Also you don't need the `-e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root` parameter when using the root user.