# Remote access to MySQL server on Virtual Machine

Tags: mysql, server, connection, virtual-machine

I have problem with setup the MySQL to have an remote access.

So, what I'm trying:
 1. I have Virtual Machine (Virtual Box) with FreeBSD installed
 2. I have installed MySQL server and configured with mysql_secure_installation
 3. I MUST use bridged adapter (all machines in the LAN should be able to connect to the database in the VirtualMachine)

So, I set the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 but without luck, maybe the problem is with the ports (I'm not able to make port forwarding), or... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...

by default, root user is not able to login remotely.
There have 2 ways to login remotely to the mysql.

1. Create new user with all privileges.
2. Add privileges to root user

For both of two ways you need to edit my.cnf and to change bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 or you can check this answer:
[MySQL root access from all hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223235/mysql-root-access-from-all-hosts)

Thanks!