# Mysql[MariaDB] - Unknow error 1130

Tags: mysql, mariadb, archlinux

I'm trying to connect to a database and I'm getting this error:

`ERROR 1130 (HY000): Unknown error 1130`

Here is a command which I'm using:

`mysql --host HOSTNAME --user MYUSERNAME -p MYDATABASENAME`

I'm using Arch Linux. Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 0):

mysql --host HOSTNAME --user MYUSERNAME -p MYDATABASENAME

MYDATABASENAME - Should be Password not DatabaseName..

```
Syntax: 
shell> mysql --host=localhost --user=myname --password=password mydb 
shell> mysql -h localhost -u myname -ppassword mydb
```

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html

Comment: Nope, same error. It works with localhost but doesn't with outside connections.

Comment: Is there any specific port and host name defined. Cross check and use them. It should work.

Comment: No there isn't any port.

Comment: Any luck? If it is different issue and if you get a solution, please update your question with your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ERROR 1130` translates into `Host '<hostname/IP>' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server`, not sure why you see it as unknown error.

It means that there are no users configured with host=`<your hostname/IP>` on the server where you are connecting to -- that is, there is no user `MYUSERNAME@<your hostname/IP>`, or even `<anything>@<your hostname/IP>`, or `<anything>@'%'`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is similar to [phpMyAdmin Remote Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766855/phpmyadmin-remote-access/48771122#48771122)

Basically you have to first configure remote access. Here is a link for MariaDB on Arch Linux remote access configuration. https://dominicm.com/install-mysql-mariadb-on-arch-linux/

Edit config locally.

Config file `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Grant privilege to table for user

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'dbusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'dbpassword';`

Restart Mysql/MariaDB

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try `mysqld --skip-grant-table`
Not sure why but it helped my teammate as she reported.

More details here. https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords