# MySQL: Cannot connect to MySql on Sequel Pro after 5.5 to 5.7 upgrade

Tags: mysql

I have upgraded my MySql Server from 5.5 version to 5.7 version. While using 5.5 version, I could connect via *mysql -u #user -p#pass* command in terminal or using Sequel Pro (management system).

I have upgraded version by:

```
$ wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.6.0-1_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.6.0-1_all.deb
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Now at 5.7 version I can still log in into MySql with *root* user using terminal (same settings as one on 5.5 version), but Sequel Pro refuses to connect with error:

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.
>
> Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary
>   privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10
>   seconds).
>
> MySQL said: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial
>   communication packet', system error: 0

I got debian under vagrant on mac os.

Comment: did you check if the mysql process is actually running?

Comment: @ADyson service mysql status > Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-07-04 15:28:07 GMT; 31min ago

Comment: what settings are you using to connect from terminal and the SQL Pro software? Are they the same? Have you maybe swapped "localhost" for "127.0.0.1" in one of them perhaps? Is MySQL still bound to listen on both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have succeeded following

> [MySQL root access from all hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223235/mysql-root-access-from-all-hosts)

answer under **b)**.

Note:

```
Update For Ubuntu 16:

Config file is (now)

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```