# Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: xampp, php-7.3

when i start connect to my database using xampp it doesn't work and show me this error:

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to connect via command line (or some other utility, like MySQL Developer)?

There are a few possibilities (probably more, but for time's sake):

- You are trying the wrong password (here's a great reference guide from MySQL on how to reset passwords: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html)
- The 'root' user is only allowed to connect using unix_socket (here's the doc from MariaDB [a fork of MySQL] describing how to switch to native password authentication instead of unix_socket: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#switching-to-password-based-authentication)
- The 'root' user is not allowed to connect from 'localhost', and must come from some other IP address (or socket) (here's a great SO answer on how to allow root from more than localhost: [MySQL root access from all hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223235/mysql-root-access-from-all-hosts))