Connection denied with MYSQL db when node app dockerized
I have a problem with connecting my node app container to MySQL database. When -compose up I keep getting error from container logs:
server-1  | Unable to connect to database AccessDeniedError [SequelizeAccessDeniedError]: Access denied for user 'admin'@'172.20.0.3' (using password: YES)
I tried manually starting the node container in docker desktop, and was getting the same errors.
The MySQL was throwing in logs healtchecks:
mysql2    | 2024-10-12T13:14:34.902593Z 8 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
mysql2    | 2024-10-12T13:14:53.729037Z 9 [Note] Access denied for user 'admin'@'172.20.0.3' (using password: YES)
Here is my db instance:
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
require("dotenv").config();

const sequelize = new Sequelize("admin", "password", "table", {
  host: "mysql2",
  dialect: "mysql",
  port: 3306,
});

module.exports = sequelize;

Docker compose file:
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    container_name: mysql2
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost", "-p'password'"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s

and Dockerfile:
Docker file: 

FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /server

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["node", "index.js"]

I tried creating just a MYSQL container and have been able to initialize db and connect to port in workbench. I tried having MySQL container with the node container in the same docker network, and I was getting the same errors. I tried with different versions, node:18, 20 and 22 alpine, and MySQL 8.0, 9.0.1 and 8.0.33.
I also tried to docker inspect the MYSQL container, finding gateway ip, using that ip as a host, all it would do is change the errors to that ip.
Just wanna point out I am using Sequelize in my app.

Either mysql is not running or mysql is not configured to listen to remote connections.

What happens when you use the alternative docker file?

On your first answer, second taught would be more likelly possible. How to check if it's listening for connections?

I had put the answer in main thread, what happened when I ran alternative docker compose.

Please edit the entire question as your alternative docker file answers your original question. The question title no longer resembles your issue. Access denied: please do some search on SO before asking that question. Asked on a daily basis...

I don't think you are right. I edited, and when running my alternative docker compose I still get refused connection.

Your edit to the question says access denied error message. That's not the same as connection refused.

You are right, I edited that.

Bot connection denied, but access deniex. And check the answers to the duplicate question. Please, please search SO before asking a question!

Gotta thank you man. Found the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430593/how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-root172-22-0-4-using-password-yes-wh

Add a shared network in docker-compose.yml to ensure connectivity:
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
services:
  server:
    networks:
      - app-network
  mysql:
    networks:
      - app-network


Tried, does not change anything. Docker already associates the containers in docker-compose.yaml.
