# Unable to connect Mysql 8 running on docker with mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I have a docker setup that is running Mysql 8.

I am able to access Mysql inside docker container, however, I am unable to connect using Mysql workbench. I have another mysql container but this one is Mysql version 5.7 and I have no issues connecting with that one.

I have tried to allow root user full host access with % in the mysql.user

```
| root             | %         |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
```

I have tried to connect to container using hostnames: localhost, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1
and port 3306 but no luck

I also created a separate user and gave full privilege and still no luck

Below is my Docker compose file

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  database:
    build:
      context: ./images/mysql
    restart: always
    command: ['--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=inim
      - MYSQL_USER=inimuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=inimpass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./database/data:/var/lib

volumes:
  my-datavolume:
```

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:8.0.20

CMD ["mysqld"]

EXPOSE 3306
```

Below is my Docker PS

```
b8832d9711b4        docker_inim_db_database   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp          docker_inim_db_database_1
```

I have a similar setup with Mysql 5.7 and it connects fine. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Any errors? Are you using the correct version of MySQL WB for MySQL 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your process by going to the container.
Please run:

```
$ docker exec docker_inim_db_database_1 /bin/bash
```

Now you should be in bash of the container.
Then login to mysql bash using:

```
$ mysql -uroot -p
```

and type your password or just press Enter if none.

There's two steps in that process:

a) Grant privileges. As root user execute with this substituting 'password' with your current root password :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

b) bind to all addresses:

The easiest way is to comment out the line in your my.cnf file:

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

and restart mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

By default it binds only to localhost, but if you comment the line it binds to all interfaces it finds. Commenting out the line is equivalent to bind-address=*.

To check where mysql service has binded execute as root:

```
netstat -tupan | grep mysql
```

Update For Ubuntu 16:

Config file is (now)

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Most of steps above are from answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11225588/659077