# can not connect to mysql container with 172.19.0.1

Tags: mysql, docker

I try to start MySQL server with docker-compose. Here is docker-compose.yaml part:

```
  mysql:
    image: debezium/example-mysql
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debezium
     - MYSQL_USER=mysqluser
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw
```

moreover I started a django application with setting

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DB_NAME', default='db_eddy_backend'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('MYSQL_USER', default='eddy_backend'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD', default='mysqlpassword'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('MYSQL_HOST', default='127.0.0.1'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PORT', default='3306'),
    }
}
```

however the django starts it pops out an error message saying

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'eddy_backend'@'172.19.0.1' (using password: YES)")
```

what is wrong? and how to deal with it?

Thanks to nbk's help, I tried

I tried

```
docker exec -it 4ac01eb11bf7 mysql -uroot -p, 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'debezium';
```

but the output is

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected.
```

And django app still met the same problem

Comment: use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11225588/5193536

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL root access from all hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223235/mysql-root-access-from-all-hosts)

Comment: I tried       docker exec -it 4ac01eb11bf7  mysql -uroot -p,    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'debezium';   but it outputs 
Query OK, 0 rows affected.  And django app still met the same problem

Comment: you dind't understand the cncept, you need to ` GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \*.\* TO 'eddy_backend'@'%' ;` because this user needs access from remote, root has already all privileges

Answer (score 1):

You should check if there is the service mysql and django on the same net

Review your networks of docker:

```
sudo docker network ls
```

Inspect your network and make sure if there are the two services running on the same net

```
sudo docker inspect <the_name_net>
```

*Also is important to view the correct ip service:

```
sudo docker inspect <the_net_id> | jq '.[].NetworkSettings.IPAddress'
```