# MySQL Database access ok with localhost but not with remote access

Tags: mysql, database, qt, networking, database-replication

I'm currently developping an app with Qt and I have some trouble with the database. I did all the development with a local database (MySQL) and it was all right, but now I want to set my app up on the network and I have some trouble. 
The network is composed of 2 pc, one with the server running and the other one with the application. Both of those have a MySQL database running, in fact I set up a database replication Master-Master. So when a change occur on one of the database the other get automaticaly the same change. With my app I can configure the path of the database, the username, the password and the database's name. 
When I want to connect with my app it's working when I put localhost for the path, but when I put the ip of the computer it's not working. So even if I want to connect on the database on the same pc it's not working when I put the local ip instead of localhost.

Don't hesitate if you have more questions.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection

Comment: I'm connecting with root access. Do you think it still could be a grant issue ?

Comment: `localhost` and `%` are two different things as far as access control goes.

Comment: @Baptiste Em, yes. Definitely. This has nothing to do with your unix permissions. This has to do with the mysql security concept.

Comment: When I said I'm connecting with root access I'm talking about root access on MySQL, not on Linux (I'm running on Windows). I'm using the user root to access the database.

Comment: If you solved your problem, please write the answer and accept it. If not and this question is still actual, please specify which error you have.