# Mysql DB connection with JDBC freezing program

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I have the MySQL JDBC library added to my eclipse project but I still cant connect to a database, the program doesn't throw an error, it just freezes on me. Here's the link to the Library I used http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j and my current code ( username, host, and passwords omitted.

```
  private Connection connect = null;
  private Statement statement = null;
  private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
  private ResultSet resultSet = null;

@Override
    try {
          // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          // Setup the connection with the DB
          connect = DriverManager
              .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://host:8080/feedback?"
                  + "user=******Admin&password=********");

          // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
          statement = connect.createStatement();
          // Result set get the result of the SQL query
          System.out.println("Connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Connection failed");
```

**SOLUTION**
I had the port wrong, the driver installed improperly AND the database name was wrong.
Here was the correct connection line after fixing the driver.

```
 connect = DriverManager
                  .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DataBase?"
                      + "user=****Admin&password=*******");
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger to find out where the program freezes?

Comment: Issue is probably in username and password parameters.

Comment: I run it in eclipse with my personal method of debugging (adding comments as checkpoints) and narrowed it down to the connection line as fault. When i enter intentionally wrong details for the connection it will throw an exception and it is caught in the catch.

Comment: Just tested with a faulty username and got the same result.. crashed program. The user exists.. I think? I couldnt change the MySQL root password so I created a new user in phpmyadmin

Comment: @brano88 This is the correct way of specifying credentials (the other is to specify them as parameters, but both work perfectly). If credentials are incorrect an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Just checked and the user does exist in my MySQL DB.

Comment: have you enabled [remote access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection) for the user? In case the server is remote ... And the port ... 8080, are you sure that's correct?

Comment: The host was set to % for the user with all privileges. I'll double check

Comment: The server is running locally on my laptop

Answer (score 4):

Try to connect in the format

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:port","username" , "password");
```

Please use the latest driver that fits you mysql version.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you changed the port of your MySQL server to 8080, your jdbc url is wrong. If you have not changed the default port, then you should use `jdbc:mysql://host/feedback?user=******Admin&password=********`.

Comment: the host is correct, it throws an error if it is wrong. Ive already tested that.

Comment: @user2341336 ok, but what about with the port? 8080 is usually a webcontainer (like tomcat),  mysql's default port is 3306, which you can omit, if you have not changed it, this is what I am pointing on in my answer

Comment: i'll try that, Im using wamp running a webserver off of port 8080

Comment: Exception thrown and printed Connection failed.

Comment: @user2341336 by the way, if you have your mysql running locally, then you should use `localhost` instead of `host`

Comment: how can I run it with say the root user that has no password? MySQL command line errors when I try and set it so I gave up.

Comment: the real connection is localhost:8080 in the code, I omitted it for reasons I myself don't even understand

Comment: @user2341336 I think the correct url is `jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?user=******Admin&password=********` then