# MYSQL Remote Connection Coda 2

Tags: mysql, connection, xampp, coda

I just bought Coda 2 and I want to try this feature about mysql database connection. I´m not able to connect. The error that appears is:

```
Unable to connect to host 1.2.3.4, or the request timed out.
Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges,
or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 0 seconds).

MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '1.2.3.4' (60)
```

The error takes 60 seconds to appear. For easy answers, Il´l make an example:

Server IP: 1.2.3.4

MYSQL Username: root

MYSQL Password: 1234root

I use xampp on a windows server. How can I connect to the mysql database remotely? About the privileges, the account I use for root has all privileges. Thank you and have wonderful holidays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your mysql server to allow remote access to root, usually a very bad idea.  Remote access is bad enough.  You would need to permit remote access and grant the root user at your remote address access.

see [Enable remote MySQL connection: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection)

This is why people usually install something like phpMyAdmin to get this kind of access.  Setting up a non root user is another choice.