# PHP database, how to connect to HTML5 application outside university.

Tags: database, html, mobile, phpmyadmin, myeclipse

Using a program called Myeclipse which is very similar to eclipse but easier to use, I am trying to link my university database (phpmyadmin) to my HTML5 application through PHP, how would I go about this, I know how to connect to the database when on site in the university but don't know how to go about it elsewhere. I need the database to use the login and also save files to.

Comment: My university that I attended didn't permit any access from external network so I had to be on campus to access mysql.  So, I'd suggest you to double check with university about allowing access to mysql database from outside network.  It'd save you so much hours that I have wasted trying to get it to work (and never did until I found out that university turned that feature off).

Comment: So your HTML5 application is not hosted on the university servers, but you wish to use the database that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try:

> host=UNIVERSITYIPADRESS

For a more detailed explanation (if above fails) look here: 
[Enable remote MySQL connection: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection)