# python connection to the database not connecting

Tags: python, sql, database

I have a simple question please

When I put data into the local host server's database via python, i do the following

```
db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "Database")
```

Now i have just for a hostgator server which me and my friend share

The snapshot of the Cpanel's database section is as attached.

[image]

Now what should i input in the following code for connecting to the database

```
db= MySQLdb.connect( , , ,)
```

I have tried this but failed]

```
db= MySQLdb.connect("moeenmh.com","moeenmh_ahmed","<mypass>","moeenmh_ahmed")
```

The user I created for my self is moeenmh_ahmed and have a password for it]

Error is `"Access denied for user 'moeenmh_ahmed'@'91.74.98.6' (using password: YES)")`

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `password` of mysql database or your `account` password? Most of the time the hosting services provide a username and password which is relative to your web app or account. But the account password and the mysql password is different. You might wanna check that out.

Comment: i am using the pas of the user i created. the other pass is Cpanel's password

Comment: It's obviously is some kind of access rights issue. You can probably conatact Hostgatr tech support since they will know what kind of access rights are given and in what case access is denied cuz they know the server configuration while we don't. It may help. Also try ssh into your hosting (if the rights are given) and try using mysql command line program to login into the database. If it works there, then it's obvious that you don't have remote access.

Answer (score 0):

Your database name has to be the full name, not just the `_ahmed` part. So it should be `moeemnh_adhmed`. Protocol should be 'TCP' for remote connections.

Also, check if you have configured MySQL for remote connections. So first try to connect to it using:
`mysql -u moeenmh_ahmed -h moeenmh.com -p`

And see this SO answer for setting up the privileges: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12844804/1431750. Quoting:

> You have to put this as root:
>
> ```
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'USERNAME'@'IP'  IDENTIFIED  BY  'PASSWORD';
> ```
>
> where IP is the IP you want to allow acess and USERNAME is the user you use to connect
>
> If you want to allow access from any IP just put % instead of your IP
>
> and then you only have to put
>
> ```
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES
> ```
>
> or restart mysql server and that's it

Comment: where should i put this command? in the terminal? mysql -u moeenmh_ahmed -h moeenmh.com -p

Comment: can u guide me how to enter myswl via terminal?

Comment: what OS are you on? There's `cmd`/command prompt on Windows. On Linux, "terminal" should be in your menu.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the Cpanel screen shot that moeenmh_ahmed doesn't have access to moeenmh_ahmed DB.
You can see in Cpanel documentation how to do it:
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/MySQLDatabases#Define a User's Privileges

Comment: all privileges have been given