# Remote Connection to MySQL Server

Tags: java, mysql, networking, ip

hello there I am new to MySQL Server and I want to connect to MySQL DataBase remotely from my computer other than database placed on! My IP on machine on which I have MySQL server is:

```
 39.32.58.13
```

and I am using this code to connect:

```
    private Connection connect = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;

    private void Connect(){
        try{
        // this will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      // setup the connection with the DB.
      connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://39.32.222.77:3306/test","myname", "mypass");
      }
}
```

---

But it gives me an error all the time:

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

---

Is it me doing something wrong because I'm doing it for the first time and need instructions on how to do it ! so please dont mind my mistakes thanks in advance

Comment: If the IP of the machine where MySQL server is the first one, why are you using another one in the connection parameter? BTW: Why MySQL and not MariaDB?

Answer (score 2):

You need to grant permission for using mysql fro remote location.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%.example.com' 
    IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'Password' 
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

where user can be root or any other user

see this for more [info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) on grant

Comment: @user432 I just gave an example

Comment: @user432 we do not know what all privileges user want to set so I gave an example and a link also.NOw OP can get to know what all privileges he/she needs to keep his/her database secured

Comment: i have given the grant though the error is stil there on my second computer where i want to access the database

Comment: tried with it! same error

Comment: @user3411946 show me how you tried

Answer (score 1):

First,check if the remote mysql database is running.
Second,check if your mysql accound has rights to access the database

hope to help you !

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this as root:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'USERNAME'@'IP'  IDENTIFIED  BY  'PASSWORD';
```

where IP is the IP you want to allow acess and USERNAME is the user you use to connect

If you want to allow access from any IP just put % instead of your IP

and then you only have to put

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

or restart mysql server and that's it.

[Here's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection)

[Another Tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Comment: Instead of linking another Stackoverflow answer here you can better close it as duplicate

Comment: @JqueryLearner - OK my mistake sir, from next time I ll keep in mind.