# How to connect to digitalocean mysql server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have a droplet on digital ocean, but how am I suppose to connect to the mysql server on my droplet?
When I try to connect to the IP with my mysql credentials it's not working. Do I have to enter something else as hostname?

Comment: If you're using the DigitalOcean LAMP one-click app, the MySql server is only available on localhost by default. To enable remote connections check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection

Answer (score 1):

From console execute:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Then edit section [mysqld], change this line:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

To this:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `localhost` as server in MySQL connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Add port 3306 (default port) to the address if you don't have it.