# How to allow a specified external IP to insert to the mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wamp

I've made a website for my friend and we're having an issue with mysql.
The plan is to use a program which I created using C# (far from finished) instead of an admin area on the website itself.
The program insert a image from a specified location on the pc, e.g: `uploadFile(@"D:\image.jpg");`Which works without any problem both for me and for my friend.

The program then inserts a row to the database table e.g:

`sqlClient.Insert("images", "title, alternative, type, slider, image", "'none', 'none', '1', '0', 'image.jpg'");`

So the website understand what image it is and where to display it on the website.

The insert works locally on my computer where i set up the server to make the website visible to the world (which it is).

However when my friend in this case tries to insert the same thing to the database from his pc, in his home, using the same program it only uploads the file to the ftp, but it does not insert anything to the database (I believe it's because mysql only allow local connections to insert to the database).

I've forwarded every port I've come across that might help me solve the issue to allow external ip's to upload to the ftp, sql and gain access to the site itself.

`Ports forwarded: 20, 21, 80, 443, 3306, 50000-51000`

The forwards have been made in both the router and windows firewall.

I've been searching on this matter for a couple of days but still haven't been able to locate a answer/ fix for this so i believe this is my last resort.

So the question is as the subject:
How can i allow just my friend to insert rows to the mysql database on my server(pc) using the program?
An IP whitelist or something?

I would be so happy if you can help me make this work :D

## edit

A different way to ask the question would be "How to enable remote access to wamps mysql database"?

---

Or you could say allow external ip address to insert data to wamps mysql(apache i believe?)

---

I've tried adding users in phpmyadmin with allow any host with no success (also included the new user in the c# program as well ofc).

---

I've seen a few people allowing external connections/IP's (remote(?)) by changing a sql file in the etc folder, however i do not have this file, i believe it's because i don't have a sql server installed since i use wamp and its built-in mysql system.

---

## /edit

Comment: Is this `C#` program run from a browser or delivered to a remote PC to be run there?

Comment: You probably need to port-forward mysql's port (3306 by default). Also you need to allow remote connection for the mysql user (assuming your app connects to mysql directly)  By the way this is likely to be off-topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's from a remote PC, as stated works well on my pc(the local) which is the problem. Not quite sure how i can allow his external IP address to insert things to the database (mysql), the database is run from wamps phpmyadmin, i've also tried adding users which allow all hosts, but it still wont work, i think i have to change something in wamp.

Comment: @RandomSeed I'm already forwarding that port, as well as 80 and a few others for ftp. Both in the router and windows firewall

Comment: There are several things to take care of to allow remote connection to your MySQL server. [Here are a few](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8380797/1446005). It would be interesting to see the error log from your remote client.

Comment: @RandomSeed I just got it to work 1h ago, the problem was that i used wamps mysql, i had to download a mysql server and run through that server rather than wamp which solved my problem. Thanks for taking your time and trying to help with this issue. Now i just have to complete building the program to make all functions work :)