# PHP & MYSQLI, why won't it even try connect to remote host?

Tags: php, mysqli, remote-access

My code is simply:

`$connection = new mysqli('52.62.xx.xx', $myUsr, $myPwd, $myDB, '3306');`

The strange thing is that the IP address, or remote host, is being replaced with the IP address of my server, and I get the following error:

`Access denied for user 'myUsr'@'107.191.xx.xx'`

Why is mysqli trying to connect to `107.191.xx.xx` when I'm explicitly telling it to connect to `52.62.xx.xx`

What am I missing here?

I don't think it's too relevant, but the remote host is an Amazon Aurora instance.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so on the HOST server I ran:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myUsr'@'107.191.xx.xx' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'`

Now it works :)

Comment: `Access denied for user 'myUsr'@'107.191.xx.xx'` is the correct error message.  Have you set up the remote host to accept connections from `107.191.xx.xx`

Comment: Don't you have to use the host *name* with an RDS? From the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Connect.html) *For host or host name, specify mycluster.cluster-123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable remote MySQL connection: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user)

Comment: I've tried with both the hostname and ip. Same thing. Yes, the remote host is setup to accept connections from 107.191.xx.xx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
`Access denied for user 'myUsr'@'107.191.xx.xx'`
```

mean that user `myUsr` tried connect from IP 107.191.xx.xx. This is your IP address of server with your script.

You  should configure the HOST mysql server to allow `myUsr` to connect from this IP or from all addresses.

Comment: The host server is configured to accept connections from 107.191.xx.xx

Comment: In your update you granted access from 52.62.xx.xx not from 107.191.xx.xx

Comment: Yes, you're right. Edited the question again, now it's working.

Comment: I was confused about on which server to grant those priviledges

Answer (score 0):

Hi you must grant your user to connect from the your local IP remotely to mysql server, your user doesn't have the right to use remote connection to mysql
you can try this command to make your user able to connect to mysql server from you local IP address 
  GRANT ALL ON youDB.* TO youUser@'YOUR_LOCAL_IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'USER_PASSWOR';