# How to export data from Access 2013 in windows 7 to mariaDB on Debian 8.4 server?

Tags: mysql, linux, ms-access, odbc, mariadb

If there is a better place to post this question then can someone please move it?

I have data that I pull from a database using an ODBC connection and then query it in MS Access on my PC running Windows 7. Now I need to push this queried data to a different database (a mariaDB database) which is located in a linux Debian 8.4 server which I connect to through mRemoteNG (a secure shell connection). I don't know how to do this last step. How can I configure mariaDB or Access (I'm not sure which one I need to configure) to send data from Access to mariaDB?

Comment: Are you able to configure your server for MariaDB to accept direct database connections from your other (Access) machine on port 3306 (or whatever)?

Comment: @GordThompson no I am not, please read the comment on Jonny's answer below.

Comment: Actually, based on the error message in your comment it does look like a direct connection might well be possible once you've told MariaDB to accept connections from `root@your_workstation_name_or_ip`. Google "mysql permissions" (or similar) to see what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add an ODBC-Connection in your windows computer using a mySql-driver and push data from access that way.

Comment: I downloaded the mySql driver and set it up. I entered the IP address, username and password (which in this case are the same for accessing the server as well as the mariaDB database). I clicked the "Test" button but it says "Connection Failed [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver] Access denied for user 'root'@'example'(using password: YES):" The password is not YES by the way. What is causing this problem?

Comment: @Michael - Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8380797/2144390) might help.

Comment: Make sure you have granted the account sufficent perrmissions including your ipadress (or all ipadresses).
It could be a firewall related problem as well, if the port (3306) is not open on the debian server.

Comment: The server went down and I am waiting for someone to fix it. I'll keep you posted.