# access denied in jdbc connecting to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, database-connection

my database name is :

```
test
```

i gave :

```
grant all on test.* to 'me' identified by 'foolinGAround_8-'
```

and when i try to connect through jdbc i am getting

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'me'@'%' to database 'test/'

what is the reason and how can I solve it?

Comment: `select user,host from mysql.user where user='me'`

Comment: sorry mr Drew i am new to both sql and java i cant understand you answer please forgive me .

Comment: can you please elabrate so it will be help ful for me

Comment: Your user does not have remote access. Use `grant all on test.* to 'me'@'%' identified by 'foolinGAround_8-'`

Comment: no still i get the same sql exception Mr Leon

Comment: connect using the root/master user and run `select user,host from mysql.user where user='me'` - edit your question to show the output

Comment: Have you used `flush privileges` or restarted the MySQL server? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user?rq=1

Comment: i havent flush privileges but restarted my sql many times

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test/","me","foolinGAround_8-"); 
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");

Comment: i gave the above in java and when trying to run the java code getting error

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'me'@'%' to database 'test/'

Answer (score 2):

try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'me'@'%'IDENTIFIED BY 'foolinGAround_8-' WITH GRANT OPTION;`