# How to establish connection to remote SQL in Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

How do I connect my app to the remote SQL i.e.: http://database.xxx.xxx// in Laravel? I tried to set the `DB_HOST` to the website address in .env file, but could not make it to work.

Comment: It has nothing much to do with laravel actually. Have you actually succeeded in connecting from the machine to the remote mysql using any mysql client?

Comment: If the local machine has `mysql` command installed, try connecting to it by running in the console `mysql -h "database.xxx.xxx" -u "username" -p`. If it's on a desktop that you can run GUI application, install any mysql clients such as [sqlyog](https://github.com/webyog/sqlyog-community/wiki/Downloads) or [SequelPro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) and try out the connection.

Comment: I tried to connect locally by specifying its IP address..
But why is that it says access denied@different_IP_address..

Why is the access denied point to different IP address than the IP address that i specify?
@LionelChan

Comment: Enabling remote mysql access is a whole story by itself. Try googling `enable remote mysql` or something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user