# Cannot connect to SQL SERVER database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp

This is my database.php (I am using XAMPP and CODEIGNITER). I cannot connect to a SQLSERVER database (it is a mess)

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'SER054USA',//server_name
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => '45645sfd45',
    'database' => 'PROD',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I got this error massage:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it

I have tried so many times but i was not able to solve this.

I have searched a lot, seen several threads but no one really helped me.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't publish your password here!

Comment: Hi @csabinho thanks for replying!. It is just an exampel :)

Comment: @csabinho Have you got any idea? I swear, i tried so many without success :/

Comment: Are your credentials correct and does the db server accept remote connections?

Comment: Yeah, the server does accept remote connections and the credentials are correct :(

Comment: Well, then the problem is neither with PHP nor with CodeIgniter but simply with your MySQL settings...

Comment: How would you solve it?

Comment: The solution might be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user).

Comment: @csabinho this is MSSQL, not MySQL. Or at least that's what i understood :)

Comment: @Raul But why does it use `mysqli` then? And why is this post tagged with `mysql`?

Comment: Probably confusion. Let's double-check, i should have asked that first....my bad, thanks. i somehow assumed MSSQL, same as you assumed MySQL   @new_programmer what database software are you really using? MSSQL or MySQL?

Comment: @Raul sorry for the delay :( . I want to connect it to a SQL SERVER database

Comment: sql server as in microsoft mssql? then try the answer i posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database driver is wrong. mysqli is for mysql

Tou need to set your driver to `sqlsrv`

To install that, please go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 and get the driver for your appropiate php version. Once you installed it for your version of XAMPP, enable it, and set `sqlsrv` in your database config file

Restart apache and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Raul!
Could you please help me to install that driver? What should i do first?.I am pretty lost :/

Comment: Dude, i was not able to enable it :(. Could you please explain to me how to do that in XAMPP?

Comment: I'm sorry, i do not have windows - please search on SO on how to do that. Here's [an article](https://support.scriptcase.net/en-us/article/1304-installation-of-sql-server-drivers-in-a-xampp-in-production-environment) i found, hope it helps