# Host is not allowed to connect to this MySql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I am unable to connect to my server remotely.

- I've tried changing the bind-address to the IP address.
- I've tried changing to the bind to 0.0.0.0
- I've made sure that port 3306 is not blocked by the firewall
- I've added a privilege user from the requesting IP and Port and
  granted full access to that user.

None of the above changes seem to have done the trick.

The syntax I am using for the connection string is Server=;Database=dbname;Uid=userid;Pwd=pwd;

The database was set up using Xammp phpyadmin

Comment: I think this is the same question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user

Comment: Yeah, I ran through all the steps detailed in that thread, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to give your username remote access to the database.  I forget the exact steps, but I know it is under the user account options when you setup the account initially as well as when you edit it.  Make sure the user can connect from all hosts rather than just localhost.

Comment: Yeap I set the user to that they can connect from the requesting IP.

Comment: What you may try then is to find out where the block is happening.  Open the server and check the event logs and the MySQL logs.  If those do not shed any light open a telnet to the server on port 3306 and ensure it connects properly.  If it does assume it is not a networking issue and rather a permissions or setup issue with the database.