# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.3' (using password: NO)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sqlexception

I'm attempting to connect to my server's MySQL, yet I keep running into the same issue and cannot find a similar problem. My code snippet is below:

```
public class MySqlDatabaseHandler {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public MySqlDatabaseHandler(String url, String user, String password){
        /*String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.80:3306/testdb";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "rootpass";*/
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            st = con.createStatement();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
}
```

And the results I receive:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.3' (using password: NO)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1704)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at handleServer.includes.classes.Server.MySqlDatabaseHandler.<init>(MySqlDatabaseHandler.java:24)
```

By the look of things, I believe the password is never being sent to the server because of the "(using password: NO)".

I have even attempted to change the url to "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.80:3306/testdb?user=root&password=rootpass" and find myself with the same results.

MySql allows remote connection to the testing client(192.168.1.3) and has been tested with telnet, but runs into this issue with JDBC. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to me as if user 'root' on 192.168.1.3 does not exist on the server.

Comment: Root exists for localhost, 127.0.0.1, and 192.168.1.3 . All with same parameters, and the 127.0.0.1 user is working and used by phpmyadmin. What I am concerned with is the fact that the error states that I am not providing a password, which I obliviously am.

Comment: What you're doing wrong is that either the user doesn't exist, you have the wrong password, or the user doesn't have the required accesss permissions. This is a dbadmin issue, not a programming issue. `ResultSet` should not be a class member, nor `Statement`, nor, typically, `Connection`. The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2007.

Answer (score 0):

It seems something is wrong with MySQL privilege setting.You can try this,open MySQL command line prompt,run the following script:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'password' with grant option;
flush privileges;
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, MySQL allows connections from certain remote connections. I have GRANTS on localhost, 127.0.0.1, and 192.168.1.3(what I am working with). But does this explain why MySQL is stating that I am not giving a password?

Normally, if there are no privileges, a telnet connection will state such a thing however, this is not such a case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a purposeful limitation to prevent root access on a network.  Try taking a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user) for the workaround.  It's basically the same as @pigletfly's solution but with a domain name.

Comment: Changing "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.80:3306/testdb" to "jdbc:mysql://www.hikaritemple.com:3306/testdb" produced pretty much the same error, just in different ip address format. Is this what you were suggesting that I do?

Answer (score 0):

I too had same issue,saying  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) but solution was quite straight. I was using this as key--> spring.datasource.data-password instead of spring.datasource.password.