# MySQL remote connection with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, remote-access

I'm new to `MySQL` and `PHP` and using 5.0 version of php.  My requirement is to connect to a `MySQL` database which is located on another server (www.some-domain.com). My `PHP` files are located in my local system.

I have `remote server database` credentials. How do I configure these details into the `PHP` file ?

Here is my code so far:

```
mysql_connect("remote server ip", "root", "root123") or die (mysql_error ());
// Select database
mysql_select_db("resource") or die(mysql_error());
// SQL query
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM resource WHERE resource_type=11";
// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
```

> when i use above code getting below error:
>
> Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'resource'

Comment: Have you tried it and if yes, then what problem you are facing?

Comment: see sidebar it having similar questions.

Comment: [`php_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`php_mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`php_pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Try to connect using the server's IP address

Comment: And yes as CORRUPT mentioned php_mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to your mysql database in another server, you need to get the host, username and password of the database on that particular server. Like,

```
mysql_connect('server_host', 'server_db_username', 'server_db_password');
mysql_select_db('server_db_name');
```

Your code is correct. You only need to connect with the server credentials.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility, that remote connections are not allowed within MySQL Server access rules, as a common security measure. I suggest you to contact server support team for further details.

Also, I suggest to read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user).