# Connect to 2 diffrent server at same time

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I want to connect 2 diffrent DB, but I get that error:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user '*username*'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in......
```

my code:

```
$mysqli2 = new mysqli('localhost',$db_user,$db_pass, $db_name);
$mysqli2 = new mysqli('localhost',$db_user2,$db_pass2, $db_name2);
```

And I try to excute queries like this:

```
$result=$mysqli->query("select ......
$result=$mysqli2->query("select ......
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems like the connection data is wrong

Comment: the user and password is 100% correct.

Comment: Then your user doesn't have permission to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Your username or password is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql user may not have the right privileges to connect over the network.

See here : [How to grant remote access permissions to mysql server for user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user)

Answer (score 0):

check password and adress and username

use next code to connect

```
$connect1 = new mysqli(...);
$connect2 = new mysqli()
if ($connect1->connect_error)
  echo "error in 1 connection message: " . $connect1->connect_error;
if ($connect2->connect_error)
  echo "error in 2 connection message: " . $connect2->connect_error;
```

where you see a problem ?