# Multiple DB query not working on remote server

Tags: mysql

I have code that will copy a record from one database to another.

The following code works on my local test server (WAMP) but gives the error "Error: SELECT command denied to user 'dbo123456'@'localhost' for table 'names'" when I run it on the live server (1&1)

```
$con1 = mysql_connect( HOST1 , USER1 , PASS1 , "db1" );
if (!$con1)
{
  echo "Failed to connect to db1 " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$con2 = mysql_connect( HOST2 , USER2 , PASS2 , "db2" );
if (!$con2)
{
  echo "Failed to connect to db2 " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "
INSERT INTO db2.names ( title , surname )
SELECT title , surname
FROM db1.names
WHERE nameID = 1
";
$result = mysql_query( $sql );
if (!$result) {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

I have never worked with muliple databases before and can't work out what might be wrong.  Is this just a 1&1 thing or am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: did you check your user permissions?

Comment: If I connect to DB1 on it's own then it's OK.  So I am assuming it's not a perissions issue as I know that user dbo123456 has the SELECT permission

Comment: Each connection works as the database's are local to the 1&1 account.  What seems to be happening on 1&1 server is that when the second connection is made then the first connection fails.

Comment: are you positive you have the ability for said user to connect via localhost? it could be using the hosts IP or resolved host name.

Comment: Yes, while attempting to debug I tested each db connection with a seperate script.  Just double checked again and each one on their own works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can assign permissions to not only the user account (i.e., the username), but also the IPs from which they connect.  So, the user could have SELECT permissions, but not from machines other than 127.0.0.1

See this S/O post for an example of granting remote access permissions: [How to grant remote access permissions to mysql server for user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user)

That said, BEWARE: you want to be very mindful of allowing remote access and should lock it down to a select set of whitelisted IPs.  I have no idea what type of app or solution you're building, but allowing remote MySQL access over the internet is generally a Bad Idea.

Comment: Thanks Will.  At first I did not think this was the issue but it seems that the connections work independantly but when combined in a single query if fails.  I am sure this is because the databases can't see each other on the 1&1 server.  I decided to write an alternative script to solve my issue rather than start to mess with the permissions.