# on my machine localhost is different from 127.0.0.1 for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am confused. When I connect to mysql using 127.0.0.1. I get a mysql server with only test database. If I connect to database using localhost, I see my databases. Why is this.

Note, at one point I did have macports installed with mysql. But I uninstalled it and I thought I removed everything. What can I do the eliminate this issue for good ? now i use apache native installation and installed the new mysql manually

When I look at my processes on my mac, I see the following

```
root               82   0.0  0.0  2468784    424   ??  Ss   22Jan14   0:00.30 /opt/local/bin/daemondo --label=apache2 --start-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.apache2/a
root               81   0.0  0.0  2468784    392   ??  Ss   22Jan14   0:00.30 /opt/local/bin/daemondo --label=mysql5 --start-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mys
```

Could these be the macports mysql and apache that is autostarting ?? and how would I remove them from auto starting ?

[EDIT]

When I do `use mysql; SELECT user from user;` I get the following

```
+------+
| user |
+------+
| root |
| root |
|      |
| root |
|      |
| root |
+------+
```

Also keep this in mind. I use mysqlworkbench. and yes I had no password setup but when i changed the host from localhost to 127.0.0.1 I couldnt see databases; But I killed those processes above and now I get my tables both ways and I never changed any permissions

Comment: What is the result of `use mysql; select user from user` from the login that contains all the dbs?

Comment: Did you try this >> http://wary.cc/NpdvD

Comment: I think I solved my problem but it wasnt a users issue. it was a multiple processes issue. everyone convinced otherwise but I think its because of old macports mysql running

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because you have your permissions set explicitly to 'root'@'localhost'.

You may need to add 'root'@'127.0.0.1'

This post should help with how to use GRANT syntax.

[How to grant remote access permissions to mysql server for user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user)

======= From comments ========

Sounds like you might have two database instances running.

Have you tried looking through the MacPort StartupItems: [Startup Reference](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/reference.startupitems.html)

Try opening up a terminal and type: `launchctl`

See if it's in the list and unload it.

For example (***I can't see the whole line in your OP so please check/modify before running***):

-> Each line should end with a `.plist` file.

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.apache2/a....plist
sudo launchctl unload -w /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mys....plist
```

Comment: I killed those 2 processes. and now if I use localhost or 127.0.0.1 they both show the right databases; So I guess I fixed the issue. The question is how do I stop those processes I added above from auto starting on loadup

Comment: @numerical25 Adding some extra info to the post that may help.

Answer (score 0):

It's down to how the users are configured in mysql. You probably have two users, `'user'@'127.0.0.1'` and `'user'@'localhost'` with differing permissions to the databases.

Comment: I was able to kill those processes I mention above and now my issue is gone. If your assumption is correct, I should still have the issue right ?

Answer (score 0):

login as root to the mysql database
Code:

```
mysql -u root -p mysql
```

and run
Code:

```
SELECT password,host FROM user where user='root';
```

Make sure password is set to 127.0.0.1 else you will be able to login without a password:
Code:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('Add-Your_password-here');
```

**Source :** http://wary.cc/NpdvD