# Can't connect to MySQL database via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I'm building a website with a login using php and mysql. When I try to connect to the database I keep getting error:

Notice: Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'User'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have tried to set a new password or no password but keep getting this error. Does somebody know how to fix this?

I noticed this error also occurs when using mysql with java apps

I'm using phpMyAdmin with wamp

Edit: Here is the code. I replaced Username, Pass and Database by User, Pass and Database

```
DEFINE('DATABASE_USER', 'Username');
DEFINE('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'Pass');
DEFINE('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DATABASE_NAME', 'Database');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');

DEFINE('EMAIL', 'user@email.com');

DEFINE('WEBSITE_URL', 'localhost/wadistjom');

$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME);

if (!$dbc) {
   trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Maybe the matter is not the password. Maybe it's the user. Try with "user" instead of "User"

Comment: can you show your code? are you passing your connection parameters correctly?

Comment: What version of WampServer are you using?

Comment: v2.2 One more thing, when try with root it works fine but with users that I've made it won't work, altough I've used the correct settings..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PhpMyAdmin then you should be able to see all users under the "Users" tab on the PMA startpage. You can also create a new user there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure remote access is on for each user? Sounds like that could be an issue (especially if you're having the same issue with Java applications).

This could *should* work:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pa55w0rd' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

(yanked it from [How to grant remote access permissions to mysql server for user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user))

Comment: Yes, the user has all privileges so this shouldn't be the problem

Comment: @MaartenMeeusen The root userid is the SuperUser and comes by default with the ability to do everything and anything!