# Mysql_connect does not work

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so I have a webhost of 3GB storage. When I connect to this IP

> 93.119.26.250

with mysql_connect, in error log:
`Access denied for user '*censored*'@'178.156.230.2' (using password: YES)`
Why? How can i resolve this?
I tried to change the user, password, ip, but the same IP on errorlog. Is that from the webhost? If it's from the webhost, what can i do?
Thanks. Please help, please. I really need to connect to this database, so please help!!!

Comment: Do you maintain your own server? If not, contact whomever does. Is there any more output from the error log we might be able to use to help?

Comment: How are you trying to connect? Either your credentials are incorrect or if you're trying to connect using an application or straight from the command line it's possible remote connections aren't allowed

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to grant remote access permissions to mysql server for user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usual for web hosting companies to allow you to create and use one or more databases, but only if you connect from one of their servers. Their DB servers are not commonly open to the outside. In this case, the fact that the server even replies denying access, implies that this server is, at least, listening on an external interface. So, it could be a credentials issue (wrong user/pass, your IP address is not authorized, etc.)

You should check with your web hosting service to know whether they allow you to connect from outside their servers, and to check your credentials.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a part of a hosting package, that user more likely doesn't have the correct permissions (i.e. select, update, etc.) enabled.  The user might also not be authorized from the host you are connecting from (i.e. if you are connecting from a service not on your host's server).