# Connecting to a database from external server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli, xampp

Pretty much self explanatory...

But for some reason I'm getting a timeout...

Do I need to modify something at my cPanel or php.ini or httpd.conf on my Shared hosting server ?

I'm using XAMPP on my host and this is how I try to connect to my domain database :

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect (
$mySharedHostingIP,
$mySharedHostingUserName,
$mySharedHostingPassword,
$mySharedHostingDB
);
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Default settings prevent connecting from external servers. Are you sure your provides enables that?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-root

Comment: @FrEaKmAn This is exactly what I asked (if I need to modify something at my cPanel/php.ini/httpd.conf) and how do I modify. (no duplicate no worries I already saw that before I post)...

Comment: If you are getting a timeout, that sounds suspiciously like the host simply doesn't accept inbound MySQL connections and firewalls them off.  You should contact your host's support to see if they allow this behavior.

Comment: If they do, it is likely then that you'll need to `GRANT` permissions to your db users to access from remote hosts, since MySQL establishes permissions by user, host, and password as 3 separate components. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user

Comment: `Do I need to modify something at my cPanel or php.ini or httpd.conf` ... that's probably the wrong direction to look.  If you are getting a timeout *connecting to the database*, the place to look is the database, not the web server, and the database's firewall or whoever administers it (which might be you, via some kind of admin interface, but the lack of detail in the question makes it difficult to speculate what your next move should be).