# Access Denied in MySQL, just not for everything

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

MAMP Pro is running my Apache and Mysql instances. When I
`mysql -u root -p -P 8889` I get access denied. When I try to access the database through Sequel Pro I get access denied. However, my Wordpress installation is talking to the database fine, and PHPMyAdmin through MAMP is also talking to the database just fine. So what gives? I must be missing a setting or maybe I need to give Sequel Pro or the `mysql` command a socket?

Comment: I'm guessing the difference is that `phpmyadmin` and `wordpress` are running on the same machine as your mysql instance, but you are trying to connect with `Sequel Pro` remotely? Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this socket with sequel? `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`