# PDO access denied for user 'username'@'%'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to connect to a remote mysql server using a php page;
the connection itself works as a charm, but the moment i try to create the database, as it doesn't exist yet, i get this error:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user '[myusername]'@'%' to database '[mydbname]'' in [myurl]/php/db_manager.php:76

As you can see, i have access denied to "%".
Now: what is "%"?

Furthermore:

## Main file

```
private function createDB() {
if($this->cm->update("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $this->dbName . " DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;", array())) { // Error here
  $this->cm->update("USE " . $this->dbName . ";", array());
  return true;
}
return false;
}
```

$this->cm is an instance of a correctly initialized PDO wrapper

## PDO wrapper file

```
public function update($query, $values) 
try{
        $sql = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $sql->execute($values);
        return true;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $this->l->error($e); // <- Error here
        return false;
    }
}
```

$this->db is a correctly instantiated, fully connected PDO object;
These are the lines used to connect

```
$this->db = new PDO($connection, $this->db_user, $this->db_password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

I have full access on the Mysql server

Comment: Root privileges for the Mysql user is not granted. Thats why SQL server is returning this error.

Comment: I do have them, since if i connect manually to the server with my login data i can create/edit/drop databases without any issue

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try looking into it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Access denied for user '[myusername]'@'%' **to database '[mydbname]'**

MySQL permissions are granular: not all users have full access to all databases on the server.

You need to sign in with an administrator and [grant the appropriate permissions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html). For instance, to grant **full access**:

```
GRANT ALL
ON mydbname.*
TO 'myusername'@'%'
WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

... or you can be more selective to your liking:

```
GRANT SELECT, ALTER, CREATE, DELETE, DROP, INDEX, INSERT, REFERENCES, TRIGGER, UPDATE
ON mydbname.*
TO 'myusername'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Please check [Privileges Supported by MySQL](http://Privileges%20Supported%20by%20MySQL) for a full list.

`%` is a wildcard explained in detail at [Account Names and Passwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-accounts-passwords) that means "connection from any host".

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem on xampp. changed my password to auto generated password(by Generate Password Button) and then copy + paste in config file. worked successfully!

### code :

```
// config information
require_once "config.php";

// make connection string
$connection_string = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ":" . DB_PORT . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME;
$connection = null;

// show connection string
echo $connection_string."</br>";

// try to connect to db or catch exceptions
try{
    $connection = new PDO( $connection_string, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
}catch (PDOException $exc){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($exc);
    echo '</pre>';
}

echo '</br>';

// connection status
if ( $connection ) {
    echo "Connected Successfully!";
} else {
    echo "Connection Failed!";
}
```

---

### Result:

```
mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=php_pdo_db

Connected Successfully!
```

---

Answer (score 0):

In the PDO query add the port after host, (in my case changed the port to 8111) and it should work.

**code :**

```
//write in database
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host:8111;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->exec($database);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 2002) {
        header('location: step3.php?_error=Unable to Connect Database, Please make sure Host info is correct and try again !');
        exit;
    }
    elseif ($e->getCode() == 1045) {
        header('location: step3.php?_error=Unable to Connect Database, Please make sure database username and password is correct and try again !');
        exit;
    }
    elseif ($e->getCode() == 1049) {
        header('location: step3.php?_error=Unable to Connect Database, Please make sure database name is correct and try again !');
        exit;
    }
}
```