# Saving to the web host database using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm using the Laravel 5.3 and I'm trying to save the details to the live database on Hostgator. But when I use migrate it doesn't result  in the actual database. I changed the app to production mode but when I edit the .env to hostgator details all I get is access denied for user. Is there any tutorial on this?

Comment: You may not have the access to the mysql server remote access for the said database for the user you're using. Contact your administrator and get the mysql remote access for the user you're using in .env or config/database file for database connection. This solution might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user