# Connection refused to database (Symfony 5)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to connect my database to my app with Symfony but I keep getting errors.
I specify that it's not a local database. Also, I'm on Symfony 5 & PHP 7.4.

First, I put this in my .env file

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://user_xxx:pass_xxx@host_xxx:3306/db_xxx?serverVersion=5.5.68-MariaDB"
```

All these informations seems to be good.

Next, here is my doctrine.yaml file

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: '5.5.68-MariaDB'

    # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
    # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
    #server_version: '13'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

And then to test the connection to db, I made this code

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test", name="test")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->getConnection()->connect();
        $connected = $em->getConnection()->isConnected();
        var_dump($connected);
    }
}
```

[And I'm getting these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tGy3.png)

Could someone help me and tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Quite a few possible reasons.  Server isn't running.  Server is running but on a different port other than 3306.  Firewall issues.

Comment: Did you grant access for user to use remote : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user

Comment: Yes, all access are granted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved, I had to enable the extension "pdo_mysql" in my PHP.ini file.
Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score -1):

First change the port to 3307 or 3308

Like the following example:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://user_xxx:pass_xxx@host_xxx:3308/db_xxx?serverVersion=5.5.68-MariaDB
```

Comment: Sadly, it does not change anything, I got the same errors